# targetting other iframe with its id

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have three IFrame on an *index.html*

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Frame</title>
    <style>
.Top {
    float:both;
    width:99.7%;
    height:18%;
}
.menu {
    float:left;
    width:13%;
    height:82%;
}
.mainContent {
    float:left;
    width:86.5%;
    height:82%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe class="Top" src="judul.html" id="atas"></iframe>
    <iframe class="menu" src="list.html" id="kiri"></iframe>
    <iframe class="mainContent" src="" id="tengah"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the code of *list.html*

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br></br>
    <a href="about.html" target="tengah" style="color:blue;margin-center:40px;font-family:Segoe UI;">Main page</a>
    <br></br>
    <a href="list.html" target="tengah" style="color:blue;margin-center:40px;font-family:Segoe UI;">About Us</a>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see from the *index.html*,what i'm trying to do is targetting the IFrame with id `tengah` to open the link from *list.html*

as far i know adding tag `target=` along with `href` will work on frameset,so it is diffrence on IFrame ? then what should i add  and where ?

thankyou

P.S.: Don't bother about *judul.html* it's only does it things on the *Top* frame it won't bother the other IFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `name="tengah"`

```
<a target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename">
```

**_blank**     Opens the linked document in a new window or tab

**_self**  Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)

**_parent**     Opens the linked document in the parent frame

**_top**    Opens the linked document in the full body of the window

**framename**  Opens the linked document in a named frame

```
 <iframe class="mainContent" src="" id="tengah" name="tengah" ></iframe>
```

Comment: So it mean it cannot targtting based on id ? well it sound silly but how can i targetting the frame if i must use the id instead it's name ?

Comment: Yes, You need to use name for the frames